# Pattern to organize related items into groups

Tags: python, django, models

Let me try to explain what I want to achieve by a small example application. It is a shopping list application that lets you add predefined `Items` to your `ShoppingList` as `Groceries`. The smart thing would be that every `Item` is related to a `Store`.

[image: model]

When I am done adding groceries to my shopping list, I should be able to see my shopping list with the groceries organized (grouped) by their Store. Something like:

[image: template]

How would I create a view and template to group and display this shopping list?

For example: this is how I would display the full inventory of all stores:

```
#views.py
store_list = Store.objects.all()

#template.html
{% for store in store_list %}
<div>{{store}}
    <ul>
    {% for item in store.item_set.all %}
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

That won't work for my shopping list, but I am really looking for something equally powerful / elegant....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the grouping in the backend of the view instead of the template.

In your view, create a dictionary like this:

```
sorted_groceries = {
    store1 : [item1, item2],
    store2 : [item3, item4],
}
```

which can be done with some code resembling this pseudo-code:

```
sorted_groceries = {}
for item in shopping cart:
    try:
        sorted_groceries[item.store].append(item)
    except KeyError:
        sorted_groceries[item.store] = [item]
```

then add it to your context and have your template look like this:

```
{% for store, items in sorted_groceries.items %}
<div>{{store}}
    <ul>
    {% for item in items %}
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: First off your "pseudo code" beats my actual Python code. How depressing is that? ;) Other than that, thanks for the elegant code. I was concerned that there would be a way to handle this in the Django model API and I overlooked it. I guess not and this works.

Answer (score 3):

What about the built in [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag?

```
{% regroup item.objects.all by store as store_groups %}

<ul>
{% for store_group in store_groups %}
    <li>{{ store_group.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in store_group.list %}
          <li>{{ item }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: That was unexpected. I did next-to-nothing with Django for about two years and I would swear that none of these goodies were available back then. Solid suggestion, this question is getting better by the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about using ifchanged https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged

Assuming shopping_list is sorted by store:

```
{% for item in shopping_list %}
     {% ifchanged %}<h3>{{ item.store.name }}</h3>{% endifchanged %}
     {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That would work for this example, not too sure I can adapt it to cover the uses cases I will encounter. Grouping in the view as per the answer by @GraphicsNoob might add some flexibility. Useful addition nonetheless.